# How to use useQuery hook without variables?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, graphql, apollo

I'm using Typescript, and I know how to use useQuery hook with variables, but now I have a GraphQL query without variables like below:

```
const GetTopAlertsQuery = gql`
  query getTopAlerts {
    getTopAlerts {
      ens
      walletAddress
    }
  }
`;
```

Basically I just need it return all the data in the database without doing any filtering. I have already implemented the back-end and it works successfully, so the query should be good.

I also have set up these two interfaces to hold the data:

```
interface topAlertValue {
  ens: string;
  walletAddress: string;
}
interface jsonData {
  topalerts: topAlertValue[];
}
```

And I have tried the below ways, but none of them work:

```
// attempt #1
const { data } = useQuery<jsonData>(
  GetTopAlertsQuery
);

// attempt #2
const data = ({ topalerts }: jsonData ) => {
  useQuery(GetTopAlertsQuery);
};

// attempt #3
const data = <Query<Data, Variables> query={GetTopAlertsQuery}>
  {({ loading, error, data }) => { ... }}
</Query>
```

If you know how to use useQuery hook without variables, please help me out! Thanks!

Comment: "but none of them work" What specifically is wrong with those attempts? Do you get error messages? Do you get unexpected values?

Comment: Those attempts didn't lead to any values. The whole app just got crashed.

Comment: "The whole app just got crashed." And what error message was thrown when the app crashed?